# Is possible to use the same instance from a class member between different classes?

Tags: c++, class

I want to use members from class A being called from class B,
does it make sense when I am actually declaring a class B inside A?

in a bigger code, I am facing that possibility and I was wondering if it is possible or I can use other alternatives/

I tried delcaring the A inside B, but it is rending and the complier does not allow to me do that. (www onlinegdb com) (using c++)

```
//main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

class A objA;

int main()
{
   A::get_instance().funA();

    return 0;
}
```

```
//a.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

class A
{
public:
    // Singleton instance
        static A& get_instance()    //static memory allocation
        {
            static A instance;
            return instance;
        }

    A();
    ~A();
    void funA();
    void funA_two();

   //Member
   B obj_b;
};
```

```
//a.cpp
#include "a.h"

A::A()
{ /*do nothing here*/}

A::~A()
{ /*do nothing here*/}

void A::funA()
{
    printf("Hello Class A\r\n");
    obj_b.funB();
}

void A::funA_two()
{
    printf("I want to be called from class B\r\n");
}
```

```
//b.h
#include <stdio.h>

class B
{
public:
    // Singleton instance
        static B& get_instance()    //static memory allocation
        {
            static B instance;
            return instance;
        }
    B();
    ~B();
    void funB();    
};
```

```
//b.cpp
#include "b.h"
//#include "a.h"

B::B()
{ /*do nothing here*/}

B::~B()
{ /*do nothing here*/}

void B::funB()
{
    printf("Hello Class B\r\n");

    //From here. how can I call the same A instance to call funA_two()?
}

actually, I would like to do some like a function pointer as C, to pass the funA_two to funB
```

Comment: Class B should have a property that contains reference to parent class A.

Comment: Or pass A in as a parameter to B's method, `B::funB(A& a)`